# vscoq language server failed installing

Tags: vscode-extensions, coq

I was following the installation guide from the main github page for installing the vscoq 2 beta release:

https://github.com/coq-community/vscoq

I am running it on WSL 2 Ubuntu on Windows 10.

```
<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
⊘ removed   coq.8.18+rc1
⊘ removed   coq-stdlib.8.18+rc1
⊘ removed   coqide-server.8.18+rc1
⊘ removed   coq-core.8.18+rc1
∗ installed coq-core.dev
∗ installed coqide-server.dev
∗ installed coq-stdlib.dev
[ERROR] The compilation of vscoq-language-server failed at "/home/username/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build dune build -p vscoq-language-server --display=short".

#=== ERROR while compiling vscoq-language-server.dev ==========================#
# context     2.0.5 | linux/x86_64 | ocaml-base-compiler.4.11.2 | https://coq.inria.fr/opam/extra-dev#2023-09-14 15:00
# path        ~/.opam/4.11.2/.opam-switch/build/vscoq-language-server.dev
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build dune build -p vscoq-language-server --display=short
# exit-code   1
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/vscoq-language-server-73968-c44b86.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/vscoq-language-server-73968-c44b86.out
### output ###
# -> required by alias language-server/install
# [...]
#     ocamldep language-server/dm/.dm.objs/dm__RawDocument.impl.d
#     ocamldep language-server/dm/.dm.objs/dm__Scheduler.intf.d
#     ocamldep language-server/dm/.dm.objs/dm__SearchQuery.intf.d
#     ocamldep language-server/dm/.dm.objs/dm__Scheduler.impl.d
#     ocamldep language-server/dm/.dm.objs/dm__SearchQuery.impl.d
#     ocamlopt language-server/language/.language.objs/native/language.{cmx,o}
#     ocamldep language-server/vscoqtop/.vscoqtop.eobjs/dune__exe__LspManager.intf.d
#     ocamldep language-server/vscoqtop/.vscoqtop.eobjs/dune__exe__LspManager.impl.d
#     ocamldep language-server/vscoqtop/.vscoqtop.eobjs/dune__exe__Vscoqtop.intf.d
#       ocamlc language-server/vscoqtop/.vscoqtop.eobjs/byte/dune__exe.{cmi,cmo,cmt}
#     ocamlopt language-server/vscoqtop/.vscoqtop.eobjs/native/dune__exe.{cmx,o}



<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build vscoq-language-server dev
└─ 
┌─ The following changes have been performed
│ ⊘ remove  coq           8.18+rc1
│ ↗ upgrade coq-core      8.18+rc1 to dev
│ ↗ upgrade coq-stdlib    8.18+rc1 to dev
│ ↗ upgrade coqide-server 8.18+rc1 to dev
└─
```

I ran the following to get that error:

```
$ opam repo add coq-core-dev https://coq.inria.fr/opam/core-dev
$ opam repo add coq-extra-dev https://coq.inria.fr/opam/extra-dev
$ opam pin add coq 8.18+rc1
$ opam install vscoq-language-server
```

Comment: I reposted the issue as an issue on the vscoq github site.  https://github.com/coq-community/vscoq/issues/620